# How to use a variable in Postman example response header

Tags: postman

We are using examples to populate our Postman mock server. This works out well, except for the tests I've written for the response headers.

In my example I've got a header that is named `Location` and it's value is `{{url}}/whatever/{{id}}`. In my tests I see only the value `/whatever/`, the other variables have not been substitued (they have been substituted in the response body).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess this was a bug that has since been fixed, this no longer happens (I tried to delete the question, but SO doesn't let me)

Answer (score 1):

Did not get it. Where wasn't it substituted? like you said:

> the other variables have not been substitued

where is it?

> In my tests I see only the value /whatever/
>   in which tests, where exactly?

Basically, there can't be any difficult situation with it for any people who works with postman at least a month, so I guess the question is hidden in more extended explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I expected: `https://localhost:8433/whatever/12345`but got `/whatever/`, so the `{{url}}` and `{{id}}` variables were not substituted with their current values.

Comment: Thanks! Could you take a look? Are these variables initialized before sending the  request. It is corny, but place a cursor on any of them and wait a bit, if they initialized(tied) then a tooltip will pop up and will show a current value in this variable, otherwise it will show Unresolved variable. Perhaps you have picked wrong Environment for this collection or environment variable is not written to Environment at all

Comment: or check, just in case maybe you made a mistake in variable name, everything can happen

Comment: The same variable is used in the response body. It is resolved there.

Comment: uh, a bit confused, don't get why {{url}} is needed in the response body. Would be great to see a video or screenshots. Please, if the issue still isn't resolved, refer to me in Telegram messenger, my nicknname: @alexdavisqa

Comment: does it matter /why/ the {{url}} is needed? Thing is: it is resolved there, so the variable is right. (btw: it is needed because the body links to other resources that have the same base url)

Comment: Ok, then i'm not getting this issue enough, without seeing it. At least I never encountered it before. But considering that fact I found at least 3 official bugs in Postman and it's found there almost every week, so I would reisntall postman and would try to see what changed or not. Otherwise the left to refer to Postman github in issues section